# Django Rest Framework CRUD

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I´m building an API with Django Rest Framework, and I’m wondering if it's enough to use only the ModelViewSet class to implement the CRUD. My worries is that it’s not enough for the frontend to consume and use the create, read, update and delete functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a short answer, "yes".

But, I would suggest you to read the official docs from DRF.

***ModelViewSet's*** [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#modelviewset)

> The `ModelViewSet` class ***`inherits`*** from `GenericAPIView` and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.

> The actions provided by the `ModelViewSet` class are ***.list()***, ***.retrieve()***, ***.create()***, ***.update()***, ***.partial_update()***, and ***.destroy()***.

***GenericAPIView's*** [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#genericapiview)

> This class `extends` REST framework's `APIView` class, adding commonly required behavior for standard list and detail views.

> Each of the `concrete generic views` provided is built by combining `GenericAPIView`, with one or more `mixin` classes.

--

There are also plenty of blogs explaining why and when to use these class.

[Django Rest Framework ViewSets](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/django-rest-framework-viewsets-2f3283dda518)

--

Lastly, I'm new to the community just like you did. I'm not sure this kind of question would be allowed here or not. But, what I'm trying to say is..

> Stop worrying, just go and try out yourself. I believe that people in the community would willing to help you out if you've stuck.